# lambdaからgoogle chat webhook経由でメッセージを送れない。

Tags: python, python3, aws-lambda

lambdaからgoogle chat webhook経由でメッセージを送れない。

同じ設定でslackのwebhookには送れます。

curlコマンド経由でメッセージは送れます。

lambdaでは正常終了してもgoogle chatには届きません。

lambdaではネットワーク・IAMロールを見直しても問題ありません。
何がいけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

pythonで出力メッセージをjson形式に変換する関数を使用することで解決しました。
エラー文はno bodyというところから推測しました。